# Azure storage container permission cannot be set

Tags: asp.net, azure

## Background

- I try to learn to use Azure blob through [azure doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-secure-access-application?toc=%2fazure%2fstorage%2fblobs%2ftoc.json).

## Troubles

- I got an error when I want to use these codes.

```
blobStorageAccount=probestudent

blobStorageAccountKey=$(az storage account keys list -g ProbeStudent \
-n $blobStorageAccount --query [0].value --output tsv) 

az storage container set-permission \ --account-name $blobStorageAccount \ --account-key $blobStorageAccountKey \ --name thumbnails  \
--public-access off
```

These codes mean that [Set container public access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-secure-access-application).

- This my container status.
  [image]
- This my storage account status. 
  [image]
- Error
  [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please remove the character `\` if the command is in one line. The symbol `\` is just used when the command is too long and need another line.

The below command is working:

```
az storage container set-permission --account-name $blobStorageAccount --account-key $blobStorageAccountKey --name thumbnails --public-access off
```

The test result:

[image]